# Start IntelliJ's "Empty Diff" via CLI

Tags: intellij-idea, diff, difftool

I currently use the cool feature via cli to diff two files:

```
$> idea diff File1 File2
```

But another cool tool is in IntelliJ to "Open blank diff window" (via find Action).

But when I run

```
$> idea diff
```

The IDE closed it directly.

Has anybody an Idea how I can directly start the Open empty diff via CLI?
Thanks!

Comment: It may be impossible without a PR to IDEA's source code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why would you like to open an empty diff via CLI? What is your use case scenario?